# Hide a field in a view if it is empty

Tags: views, entities

I customised the output of a field (using Rewrite the output of this field) but if the field is empty, only the customizations and not the content appears. I want to hide both the customizations and the content if the field is empty

Comment: Have you enabled the "Hide if empty option" present in "No results behavior" tab of field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the screenshot settings work for you,this the setting for the field you want to hide when empty. It provides option to hide the **rewritten** content as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Enable the **Hide if empty** and **Hide rewriting if empty** present in "No results behavior" tab of the field whose customization and content you want to hide as below:

[image]